# Filter on Previous Business Day in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am having a dumb problem where I can't seem to get the previous business day filter to work correctly in pandas. I know the solution is probably easy, but I can't get there. Here is the code I am using which is returning an empty dataframe. The reason I am casting the previous_day variable to datetime is because previously in the code I am casting all of my dates to this format. I originally thought the problem was related to the date type, however it persists no matter what.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
previous_day = pd.to_datetime(today - BDay(1))
df = df[(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] == previous_day)]
```

this returns the following

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Invoice Submit Date - Date, Invoice Number, Invoice ID, Invoice Date Created - Date, 
Invoice Date - Date, Approved Date - Date, Invoice Status, Preparer - User, sum(Invoice Spend)]
Index: []
```

Update: this is the result df.head() result

[image]

Comment: What is the dtype of `df[Invoice Submit Date - Date]` ?

Comment: @venky__ datetime64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but this worked for me if others are having issues:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

# filter on previous business day's date
today = dt.datetime.today()
df['previous_day'] = (today - BDay(1))
df['previous_day'] = df['previous_day'].dt.normalize()
previous_day = df['previous_day']

# new dataframe
df = df[(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date']) == previous_day]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
format = "%Y/%m/%d"
df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'],format)
```

is what you need somewhere before you do the date compare...

where the format string matches the datetime in the loaded dataframe

Comment: Still get the same result

Comment: Could you print out the df so we can see the data?

Comment: the df is empty when i run that command. the data type of the field in question is datetime64

Comment: Then there is no 'Invoice Submit Date - Date' on the previous day.

Comment: I still get the same result with this:

    today = datetime.datetime.today(),,,,
    previous_day = df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] - BDay(1).....

    df = df[(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] == previous_day)]

Comment: right when you load your dataframe could you type print(df.head())  and paste the results into the question?

Comment: i have added this

Comment: Thank you! `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`
`df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'],format)`
`testdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-12-04',format='%Y-%m-%d')`
`dftest = df[df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] == testdate]`  `print(dftest)` This should get you the row number 2 only.  That would be a good test.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I need testdate to be the previous business day, not a hard-coded date. when i try to use BDay, it still gives me no records. 

previous_day = df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] - BDay(1)

df = df[(df['Invoice Submit Date - Date'] == previous_day)]